# Is there any way to get element attribute names by Xpath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I can get attribute value of element by Xpath, but how to get all the attribute names?

example:

```
# there is an element
'<img src="http://fakesrc" alt="pic name"></img>'
i = <Element img at 0x102622cb0>

In [10]: i.xpath("//img/@src")
Out[10]: ['http://fakesrc']

In [11]: i.xpath("//img/@*")
Out[11]: ['http://fakesrc', 'pic name']
```

How can I get the the names src/alt of i?

Comment: Using `@*` should get you all the attributes. I think your problem is that when displaying them, you're only seeing the value. You would need to iterate the collection returned and get the `name` property

Comment: Indeed, I can get the names by iterating the result, but it seems have no direct way to finish this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to include namespace prefixes or not, you can choose between the following two options in XPath 2.0:

```
//@*/local-name()
//@*/name()
```

Choose a different initial context node that fits your needs and [see the specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/) for more info.

With XPath 1.0, the above is not possible.  The following *does* work, but will only show the attribute name of one attribute, even if there are multiple ones.

```
local-name(//@*)
name(//@*)
```

Comment: In lxml(Python),  i.xpath("name(//img/@*)")   I got the first attribute name only... The result is 'src' instead of ['src', 'alt']

Comment: That's because in Python you're pretty much limited to XPath 1.0.

Comment: so now I iterate the result of //@* to get attribute names, grudgingly accepted.